# How can I define the Spark UI and Driver log URLs so that they hit my proxy rather than the spark master directly

Tags: apache-spark, nginx, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

**Environment:**

- AWS EMR 5.20.0
- Spark 2.4.0
- JupyterHub
- NGINX Reverse Proxy

**Problem:**

The user logs into our proxy and is directed to a JupyterHub instance on a AWS EMR cluster. They create a Jupyter Notebook with a pyspark3 kernel and start up a Spark instance.

Ex:

`help(spark)`

Result:

```
Starting Spark application

ID  YARN Application ID Kind        State   Spark UI    Driver log  Current session?
55  application_0056    pyspark3    idle    Link        Link        ✔
```

User clicks either link and is directed to an aws internal address which is blocked.

I want these links to instead direct the user to the NGINX Proxy so that it can authorize and redirect them to the Spark UI as the proxy is allowed to access those URLs via Security groups.

**Expected Result:**

From the users perspective they would click on the link in the jupyter notebook and just end up at the Spark UI, which would reside behind the NGINX Proxy.

Currently the Spark UI link will direct the user to: http://ip-1-2-3-4:20888/proxy/application_0056

I would like to define it to point to https://proxy.company.org/spark/proxy/application_0056

**Expected Solution:**

I tried different solutions I found online, using the AWS EMR configurations to define the below, has not worked and the Spark UI links stay the same regardless of what I submit to the EMR cluster.

```
[
    {
        "classification":"spark-defaults",
        "properties":{
            "spark.ui.proxyBase":"/spark",
            "spark.ui.proxyRedirectUri":"https://proxy.company.org"
        }
    }
]
```

Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think you can change that using Spark configuration. These links work in EMR Studio notebooks.